# В чем разница между ExecutorService и ForkJoinPool?

Tags: java, многопоточность

В чем разница между старыми имплементациями `ExecutorService` из 1.5 и новой `ForkJoinPool` из 1.7? Что такое можно сделать при помощи  `ForkJoinPool`, чего не сделать с старыми вариантами `ExecutorService`? Или что **проще** сделать при помощи `ForkJoinPool`?

Comment: Вопрос изначально некорректен, т.к. одно - интерфейс, другое - имплементация.

Comment: Ну и по классике javadoc, в котором есть целая секция, начинающаяся со слов *A ForkJoinPool differs* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html

Comment: @etki в вопросе речь идет не о классах и имплементациях, а о фраемворках в целом. Как о пакетах решающих какой-то спектр проблем. Был же с 1.5 ExecutorService и жили с ним, а потом сделали ForkJoin, значит он какую-то боль снимает в отличие от прдыдущего в этом и вопрос.

Comment: И сейчас все еще живут с ним. Потому что это - интерфейс, а ForkJoinPool - его имплементация.

Comment: @etki понятно я имею в виду что эта имплементация делает нового по сравнению с вариантами из 1.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю разница тут в следующем:

1. `ExecutorService` имеет общую очередь задач и некоторое количество потоков, которые забирают по очереди таски и выполняют их.
2. `ForkJoinPool`  имеет некоторое количество потоков, но при этом еще имеет очередь тасков для каждого потока. Поток в процессе работы может дробить задачу на несколько тасков, одну он добавляет к себе в очередь а другую выполняет и это может рекурсивно повторяться. Если другой поток опустошил свою очередь, то он может взять задачи у другого потока, с конца очереди. Описанный механизм называется **work-stealing**. Это и является ключевым моментом различающим данные *thread-pool*'ы.

Рекомендуется использовать `ForkJoinPool`, если у вас есть набор задач, которые рекурсивно повторяются. Это позволяет вовсю использовать **work-stealing**. Если же задачи никак не разбиваются в процессе работы, то и выгоды никакой не получите, хотя и минусов от использование тоже не встретите.

Больше [информации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)

Answer (score 2):

Классические реализации ExecutorService создавали отдельные потоки и ими владели. ForkJoinPool же не создает отдельных потоков, а использует существующие в то время пока они "спят" на join-подобных вызовах, в этом его и достоинства, и недостатки.

Классические ExecutorService обычно нельзя использовать с задачами, которые синхронно ждут друг друга - они быстро исчерпывают доступный пул потоков, что приводит либо к взаимоблокировке, либо к его неограниченному распуханию. ForkJoinPool же такие ситуации умеет разруливать.

С другой стороны, задачи, исполняющиеся в рамках ForkJoinPool, обязаны быть достаточно короткими.

PS лично мне кажется, что любое использование ForkJoinPool является костылем для обхода проблемы слабой архитектуры

Comment: _Mayorov ExecutorService обычно нельзя использовать с задачами, которые синхронно ждут друг друга_ а как же барьеры разве не решают эту проблему?

Comment: @Павел при чем тут барьеры? Я говорю про ситуацию, когда задача вызывает метод `.get()` у другой, та - у третьей, а третья ждет четвертую. Если в пуле всего 3 потока - будет взаимоблокировка.